# os.walk() is not throwing any error nor the result in python

Tags: python-3.7, os.walk

I am trying to print the file names which are in a predefined paths where the paths are stored in paths.txt. But when I execute the below code, I'm not getting any error nor the files names printed.

```
import os
with open('D:\paths.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    path = data.split(";")
    print(path)
    for line in path:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(line):
            for name in files:
                print(name)
```

[image: Example of paths.txt]

Comment: If you remove the double quotes from paths.txt (""), does it fix your problem?

Comment: @PeterEmil removed double quotes from the file. Working perfectly fine. I have been scratching my head for the past 5 hrs for this result. I was quite confident that I need to include double quotes when assigning to a variable. So never thought to remove it. Thanks again and everyone for answering.

Comment: You're welcome, I will write a more detailed answer about why the double-quotes were causing you the problem if you want to know more.

Comment: @PeterEmil I am new to python and very much interested in learning more.

Comment: Regarding no errors, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk): *By default, errors from the scandir() call are ignored. If optional argument onerror is specified, it should be a function; it will be called with one argument, an OSError instance. It can report the error to continue with the walk, or raise the exception to abort the walk. Note that the filename is available as the filename attribute of the exception object.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the double-quotes from the file (""). Here is why; When the file gets read by Python, after it does the `.split()`, the double-quote characters are part of the Python string. So instead of passing into `os.walk()` the path `D:\bp1`, you were actually passing in `"D:\bp1"`, and there was no path that starts with a `"` that's why nothing was happening.

You would only need to provide the double quotes if you're writing the name in a terminal/command prompt and don't want to escape the double quotes, or if you're trying to define the string inside Python using the double quote literal, for example `path = "D:\\bp1"` (notice that in that case you also have to escape the `\` with another one.